# Eigenvalue assumption for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Assume $\lambda_{min}(H(t)) \geq \frac{\lambda_0}{2}$, H(t) psd matrix and $u_{nn}(t)=k\cdot u(t) $. How can I use the differential equation
$$\frac{du(t)}{dt} = -H(t) (u(t)-y)$$
to derive:
$$\| u_{nn}(t)-y\|_2 \leq exp(-\frac{k²}{2}\lambda_0t)\cdot\|u_{nn}(0)-y\|_2$$

I'm sorry if the answer is obvious but I'm a little confused ...

Comment: What's the point of this $u_{nn}$, why not just look at $u$? Unless $k$ is a vector?

Comment: It's from a paper and relevant for bounds on $u_{nn}$, it's just that I don't get this step ...

Comment: I don't see why $u_{nn}$ approaches $y$ at all. It seems like it should approach $ky$ if it has a steady state at all.

Comment: @Alice what paper?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.11955.pdf on page 26 and Lemma F.8

Comment: @Alice I cannot find in this paper that $u_{nn}=ku$. Where did you find that?

Comment: On page 4, they set $u(t) = (f(\theta(t), x_i))_{i \in n}$ and on page 6, they introduce k with $f_{nn}(\theta, x) = k \cdot f(\theta, x)$ , k is a scalar.